# Machine Learning algorithm with irregular data/variable tensor shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, physics

I want to setup a neural-network for particle physics. I will be evaluating lets say 2000 events with a variable amount of particles in those events. but 5 variables for each particle so the shape would be (2000, number of particles, 5). Right now I have setup a tensor in shape of (2000,500,5) and the variables for non existing particles in the second dimension are just 0. But I think this is misleading as it boosts the accuracy for the network even though it is not more accurate. especially when I am searching for a binary output. Right now I need a multiclass, single label, classification. How can I setup layers for variable input dimensions? Is my first approach in the wrong direction?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(500,5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500*5, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(INPUT, OUTPUT, epochs=10, batch_size=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why you may want another architecture

After reading your problem statement it sounds like you are running simulations on up to 500 particles, each with something like an x, y, dx, dy, and mass attribute (the 5 variables each)

If I was going to try and solve, by hand, a 500 particle simulation in 2D I'd probably draw out the particles in 2D and go from there because a 2D format makes sense for the problem.  Alternatively, if we just gave a spreadsheet to someone that had 500 rows and 5 columns of numbers without telling them what it means and just told them to figure it out, I bet they'd have a hard time.

Going on that intuition, and that modern machine learning is particularly good at image and 2D data these days, I'd suggest representing your data as a 2D grid, perhaps a 128x128x3 grid, where the 3 values are the total dx, dy, and mass in that grid space.  This will allow you to have as many particles or as few as you like.

The particles will interact with others in their neighbourhood, and convolution will very much help with that.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2)) # 64x54
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2)) # 32x32
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2)) # 16x16
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2)) # 8x8
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, activation="tanh", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2)) # 4x4
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 4, activation="tanh", padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 1, activation="softmax", padding="same"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(INPUT, OUTPUT, epochs=10)
```

Your output is now a softmax over 2 categories.  You could train it to answer question like: are there two particles that are close, are there three particles that are close, is the total mass above 42.  It probably won't be able to answer question like: is the total angular velocity clockwise, are all the particles going to eventually collide.

## Why Dense layers will probably not work

Let's take another look at your current architecture and see what it will have to learn in order to do well

```
2) model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(500,5)))
3) model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500*5, activation="relu"))
4) model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="softmax"))
```

If we look at line 3, it is accepting 500x5 inputs (2,500 floats) and doing a dense fully connected operation on that to output 2,500 floats.  That is a matrix with 2,500 x 2,500 parameters = 6,250,000 parameters, one for each combination of input to output.  It must learn each of these.  To draw some attention to how difficult this is, imagine the case where you have just 4 particles, A, B, C, and D.

If you train the model with the particles ordered as such ABCD, and ACDB and ADBC it will not be able to generalize to a new situation of BACD.  It has never seen B in the first position and the dense network does not have a mechanism to generalize the problem.

Compare this to the above convolution example.  Each convolution learns only how to map a 5x5 patch of the 2d world into the next smaller layer.  The 5x5 patches each only take in 16 parameters over 5x5 and map that to 16 outputs for a total of 6,400 parameters per layer. There is 7 convolution layers (the last couple are smaller, but lets ignore that) which is about 7 * 6,400 = 44,000 parameters.  A far cry from the 6 million.  Further more, these parameters are reused again and again over every position, and if they 'learn' someone in the upper right hand corner, that knowledge is applied to every part of the image.

You could try and scramble your data to make the dense layers work in line 2, scramble the order of ABCD so that you get every particle trained in every position.  For 500 positions, the number of combinations is 500 factorial, and so it isn't practical to compute.

Comment: @sergeantidiot if this answers your question then please mark it as the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers